# i want to Generate a new list containing the elements of list2 .Followed by the elements of list1 in reverse order

Tags: python, list

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
    new_list = []
    reversed_list = list1.reverse()
    new_list = list2().append(reversed_list())
    return new_list

Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you directly use:

```
print( Drews_list + Jamies_list[::-1] )
```

Lets count the faults you did in the code:

1. `new_list = list2().append(reversed_list())` must be `list2.append(list1)` and it can't be stored back in new_list because it will not create any new object it will just play with the existing one.
2. Same thing here in `new_list = list2().append(reversed_list())`. It should be
   `list2.append(reversed_list)`
3. Now lets take a case if you can successfully append the list as you want to do in your code it will return something like `['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', ['Peter', 'Jan', 'Bobby', 'Cindy', 'Alice']]` which is not correct at all.

Comment: Drews_list should go first. Check the title.

Comment: Don't forget to close the question and mark the answer as correct when you can ;) @AmirRezaAhad

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
    return list2 + list1[::-1]
```